# Titanium:Getting Nothing in when trying to access json data from remote server

Tags: titanium

```
  I have a json data in my remote server,and i want to show it in table view,here is my json data
```

[{"offerType":"Discount","offerName":"BURBERRY -  Buy 2 get 1 free on men's leather          coat     collectioN"},{"offerType":"Discount","offerName":"ARMANI JUNIOR- 20% off on                   Purchase worth INR 30000"}]

```
      var url = "http://203.122.12.58:8080/api?                username=superuser&password=superuser&action=invokeService&serviceName=offerAction&methodNa    me=getMyOffers&customerId=CUS-12220&storeId=CMPNY-3376";

var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();

 win = Ti.UI.currentWindow;  
 win.setBackgroundColor('gray');
 //win.setBackgroundColor = 'white';
  var table = Ti.UI.createTableView();
  var tableData = [];
  var json, fighters, fighter, i, row, nameLabel, nickLabel,offerType,offerName;

 var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
  onload: function() {
// Ti.API.debug(this.responseText);

json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

    console.log("json = %d",i);
    offerType = json[i].offerType;
    row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
        height:'60dp'
    });
    nameLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text:offerType,
        font:{
            fontSize:'24dp',
        fontWeight:'bold'
    },
    height:'auto',
    left:'10dp',
    top:'5dp',
    color:'#000',
    touchEnabled:false
    });
    offerName = json[i].offerName;
    nickLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text:'"' + fighter.nickname + '"',
    font:{
        fontSize:'16dp'
    },
    height:'auto',
    left:'15dp',
    bottom:'5dp',
    color:'#000',
    touchEnabled:false
    });

    row.add(nameLabel);
    row.add(nickLabel);
    tableData.push(row);
    }

table.setData(tableData);
},
 onerror: function(e) {
Ti.API.debug("STATUS: " + this.status);
Ti.API.debug("TEXT:   " + this.responseText);
Ti.API.debug("ERROR:  " + e.error);
alert('There was an error retrieving the remote data. Try again.');
},
timeout:5000
});

xhr.open("GET", url);
xhr.send();
```

how can i achieve my goal,Thanks in advance.

Akshay

Comment: Where is the error?  What exactly is empty?  json?  json.length = 0?  I presume you tested the web service response with a browser?  Please provide a few more details.

Comment: Hi Tevo,I solved my problem,actually there was problem with the emulator,when i restart my emulator it works as my expectation.Thanks for your response

Comment: But now i want to add a image to my window and i think i write the right code but i am getting the error  Resources/main_folder/imgshop.png: path not found,can you help on this.thanks Akshay

Comment: The Resources folder wouldn't likely be included in the path to the image file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was pretty close.  I did make a few changes so you'll have to compare them to see how to fix it.  This example reads your service and displays the 2 entries in a table.

See the comments in the code detailing how it was changed.

```
//**** Not sure if this is an issue with formating on Stackoverflow or copy and paste, but the spaces in the URL are causing an issue.****
//var url = "http://203.122.12.58:8080/api?                username=superuser&password=superuser&action=invokeService&serviceName=offerAction&methodNa    me=getMyOffers&customerId=CUS-12220&storeId=CMPNY-3376";
var url = "http://203.122.12.58:8080/api?username=superuser&password=superuser&action=invokeService&serviceName=offerAction&methodName=getMyOffers&customerId=CUS-12220&storeId=CMPNY-3376";

var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();
 //*****If you are calling this from another window, you may need this is your overall code, but my example I removed it.***** 
 //win = Ti.UI.currentWindow;  
win.setBackgroundColor('gray');
 //win.setBackgroundColor = 'white';
var table = Ti.UI.createTableView();
var tableData = [];
// **** Removed variable fighters because it is never used.
// **** Removed the fighter variable because it is never used.
var json, i, row, nameLabel, nickLabel, offerType, offerName;

var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload: function() {
        // Ti.API.debug(this.responseText);
        json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            console.log("json = %d",i);
            offerType = json[i].offerType;
            row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
                height:'60dp'
            });
            nameLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
                text: offerType,
                font:{
                    fontSize:'24dp',
                    fontWeight:'bold'
                },
                height:'auto',
                left:'10dp',
                top:'5dp',
                color:'#000',
                touchEnabled:false
            });
            offerName = json[i].offerName;
            nickLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            //text:'"' + fighter.nickname + '"',  ***** fighter.nickname isn't defined anywhere so it is giving an error.  You defined offerName right above it so I assume that it
            // was the intended variable here. 
                text: offerName,
                font:{
                    fontSize:'16dp'
                },
                height:'auto',
                left:'15dp',
                bottom:'5dp',
                color:'#000',
                touchEnabled:false
            });

            row.add(nameLabel);
            row.add(nickLabel);
            tableData.push(row);
        }

        table.setData(tableData);
    },
    onerror: function(e) {
        Ti.API.debug("STATUS: " + this.status);
        Ti.API.debug("TEXT:   " + this.responseText);
        Ti.API.debug("ERROR:  " + e.error);
        alert('There was an error retrieving the remote data. Try again.');
    },
    timeout:5000
});

xhr.open("GET", url);
xhr.send();
// Thought this might just be a test application, the table was never added to the window, so it would never be displayed so we can see the data.  This is how you add the table.
win.add(table);

// I added code here to OPEN the window so I could see something displayed.  Otherwise I just get the Appcelerator splash screen
win.open();
```

Comment: this is not a really useful answer for other people. Please try to explain what you changed, and what the user did wrong!

Comment: That is a good point.  I placed comments to show the before and after throughout the code.  That should make it easier to see the issues and what needs to be changed to fix it for others.